# How to structure a response with an array that has an href to itself in YAML/swagger.io?

Tags: rest, yaml, swagger

How do I do something like this:

```
"groups":{  
      "href":"https://api.mydomain.com/account/abC132/groups",
      "items":[  

      ]
   }
```

I have this:

```
groups:
            type: array
            properties:
              href:
                type: string
            items:
              type: object
              name: division
              properties:
                href:
                  type: string
                id:
                  type: string
```

But the swagger editor isn't recognizing the href under properties for the group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something along the lines of this:

```yaml
definitions:
  groups:
    title: groups
    type: object
    properties:
      href:
        type: string
      items:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/group'
  group:
    type: object
    properties:
      href:
        type: string
      id:
        type: string
```

Comment: `definitions` is the global property that allows you to define models and primitives/arrays that fall under `schema` properties to which you can `$ref` and reuse. I believe the samples show it as well. I would recommend always defining models under `schema` and never define them inline.

Comment: Thanks webron. Found it and have been using it and love it. what do you mean define the models under schema and never inline?

Comment: My bad, I meant define models under `definitions`. Just not directly inside parameters or responses.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following:

```
definitions:
  groups:
    title: groups
    type: object
    properties:
      href:
        type: string
      items:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/group'
  group:
    type: object
    properties:
      href:
        type: string
      id:
        type: string
```